# Ошибка при установке phpmyadmin

Tags: установка, php

При установке phpmyadmin происходит некая ошибка, из-за чего он естественно и не устанавливается. В переводе ошибка означает, что пакеты сломаны

> `genf103:~# apt-get install phpmyadmin
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:`
>
> `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   phpmyadmin: Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not going to be installed or
>                       php4-mcrypt but it is not installable
> E: Broken packages`

Comment: Скачайте пхпмай админ с афициального сайта и поставьте. Все должно работать.

Comment: Обновите репозитории...

Comment: А если просто файлы скопировать и руками допилить конфиг?

Answer (score 1):

установите mcrypt extension для PHP